# How set an time limit to get ping value

Tags: java, android, process, ping

I'm developing an application to check the ping and update the value for a TextView, but when it does not get the value before 1000ms the app crash. Is there a way to enforce a timeout?

Code Below:

```
public void Start() {
    Ping();
    PingUpdate();
}

public void Ping() {
    String pingString;
    try {
        Process process = Runtime.getRuntime().exec("/system/bin/ping -c 1 " + url);
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
        int i;
        char[] buffer = new char[4096];
        StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();

        while ((i = reader.read(buffer)) > 0)
        output.append(buffer, 0, i);
        reader.close();

        pingString = output.toString();

        pingString = pingString.substring(pingString.indexOf("time="), pingString.lastIndexOf("ping"));
        pingString = pingString.substring(pingString.indexOf("="), pingString.lastIndexOf("ms"));
        pingString = pingString.substring(1);

        TextView pingValue = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Ping);
        pingValue.setText(pingString);

    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        // body.append("Error\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public void PingUpdate() {
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Ping();
            PingUpdate();
        }
    }, 1000);
}
```

Comment: Why are you calling PingUpdate() recursively?

Comment: Because if I call inside Ping() void, I don't receive value